# How to align axis label to the top, aligned with the y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

By default matplotlib plots the axis label at the center of the y-axis.
I would like to move the label in such way that it is horizontally aligned (at the top) with the beginning of the y-axis.

```
label
+---------------------------+
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
+---------------------------+
```

The best I at the moment could come up with is:

```
plt.ylabel("Tasks", rotation='horizontal', horizontalalignment='left', y=1.0)
```

But as you see in the figure, the y-label is aligned with the text next to the y-axis and not with the y-axis itself. Anybody any idea how to do this?

[image: plot layout]

Another attempt:

```
plt.ylabel("Tasks", rotation='horizontal', verticalalignment='baseline', y=1.02)
```

But again, aligned with the text next to the axis (not with the y-axis itself)[image: plot y-label layout]

Comment: Would using a normal annotation work, `ax.annotate("Text", xy=(0,1), xytext=(0,3), xycoords="axes fraction", textcoords="offset points", ha="left", )`

Comment: Or you could just add a title w loc=left

Comment: True, that's an option that does the job easily! But then your title is gone.. And secondly, suppose you have a graph with 2 y-axes (one left, one right) with on each one a different y-label. What's the trick then to align both y-labels with their corresponding y-axis..?

Comment: No you can have both  a left aligned title and a Center aligned title and a right aligned title.

Comment: This is not to detract from @importanceofbeingernest s answer which is essentially all title does

Comment: Hmm that does not work for me. If I set multiple titles, they overwrite each other and only the last one is plotted.. I tried it coding them after each other and in an array (array gives even an error)

Comment: Use `ax.annotate` as commented 16 hours ago already.

Comment: Yeah sure, that worked. I was just trying out some different approaches ;-)